# Recording multiple tracks with a analog mixer

Tags: logic, behringer

I have recently purchased a Behringer Xenyx 802 mixer. It is a analog mixer that uses RCA to 3.5mm connections to my iMac's line in port.

I am using logic to record single tracks at a time, but I would like to record multiple tracks at once. For instance, Guitar and Bass.

When I make two audio tracks and select input one, and input for each of the tracks, both instruments play on both tracks at the same time.

I am wondering if it is possible to assign each instrument to its own corresponding track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a line per channel.  You have 2 lines, so you can only record two channels at a time through the mixer.  You would need to assign them to the left and right channels of your output respectively by using the pan knobs.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds like it would work but how would i get the channels into my computer since it only has one line input

Comment: Would i need a audio interface?

Comment: If you have a stereo line input, you could use that.  The best quality would be to get an ASIO interface, but you should probably be able to get stereo input through a line input if you have that.